# Pressure and state variable: Difference between compressible and incompressible

Tags: fluid-dynamics

My question: If I am simulating compressible fluids, then pressure is a "state-variable" - if incompressible, then not. Could anyone explain the difference :)? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know what the definition of incompressible is (mathematically, and note that it is different from constant-density)? I can help explain the difference, but need to know where to start from.

Comment: I know about incompressible: That a fluid has a constatn volume at pressure changes (at const. temperatures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in my comment, the definition of incompressible is key to understanding why pressure is no longer a thermodynamic variable. The definition you gave, "A fluid has constant volume at pressure changes" is correct, but I usually don't work in a pressure-volume-temperature set of state variables, I prefer to work in pressure-density-temperature. An equivalent statement is:

$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho} = \infty$$

or in your definition,

$$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial p} = 0$$

I prefer the first because it actually helps explain the mathematical nature of things when we are in incompressible flow. The speed of sound is the square root of $\partial p/\partial \rho$ and that's why we say the speed of sound is infinite in an incompressible fluid. This is what changes the nature of the system from hyperbolic (information travels in waves with finite speed) to elliptic (information is instantly felt everywhere), but that's getting off-topic.

If we consider a general, ideal gas, $\rho = P/(RT)$. But we just said that in an incompressible gas, $\partial \rho/\partial p = 0$, meaning $\rho$ is no longer a function of pressure.

Lastly, we need to remember what a thermodynamic state variable is. Given any two state variables, we can compute any other state variable.

For an incompressible fluid, if I gave you temperature and pressure, could you compute the density? By definition, you cannot -- they no longer interact -- and therefore pressure cannot be a state variable.

Comment: @lars111 I have a suspicion this may be for homework so I left out quite a bit of detail about the implications of pressure no longer being a state variable. I very much recommend spending some time to think about what all of this means and why -- it has important physical and mathematical ramifications.